# What is the name for one side of a ratio?

Tags: terminology, ratio

Basic example: "If you are asked to put a ratio in the simplest form, make sure that you have found the smallest factor that goes into both [?]."

I've tried searching for ratio diagrams in [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ratio%20diagram&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIke60poLoxgIVw1wUCh3TZQDN), with no success.

I appreciate all help

Comment: that goes into both nominator and denominator.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Make that _numerator_ and denominator.

Comment: @JackLee Oops, I was thinking of "terminator" too much.

Comment: I recommend adding some examples of actual "ratios" in mathematical notation to your question, because the first two answers that were posted referred to two different notations. Examples would clarify what you think a "ratio" is.

Comment: In fraction 4/12, 4 goes into both ( num & den)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerator and denominator refer to a fraction.  Ratios can  be expressed as fractions, but they are not quite the same thing.  For a ratio $a:b$, $a$ and $b$ are sometimes called the **terms**, with $a$ the **antecedent** and $b$ the **consequent**.

Comment: I suppose what you call the two parts of a ratio would depend on what thing you mean by "ratio" in the first place. I find people often write something like $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and call it a "ratio". I don't know if that's strictly correct, but if it is not, surely the error would only be amplified by calling $f(x)$ and $g(x)$  the "antecedent" and "consequent".

Comment: Thanks for your answer May I ask then what the two dots in between would be known as? The colon?

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{ratio}=\frac{\mathrm{numerator}}{\mathrm{denominator}}$